# Fresh install Arch Linux freeze

Tags: arch-linux, freeze

I've installed Arch Linux using linux kernel (non lts version), with amd-ucode (pacman -S amd-ucode).

The screen is totally frozen. I can't CTRL + ALT + F1, 2, 3 .. , RCTRL + F1, 2.

What can I do?

[image: Freeze login]

Comment: Have you tried logging in? I assume that fails too? What happens if you just type your username and hit enter?

Comment: maybe my keyboard stops working and it is not in fact frozen.. i don't know

Comment: I can't enter any text. It is frozen. @terdon

Comment: Since you talked about `amd-ucode`, did you load it with *initrd*?

Comment: i don't think so, how can i do that?